# How to pass a dynamic parameter between CircleCI steps

Tags: circleci, circleci-workflows

I would generate a UID in the first step of my CircleCI job. Is there a way to store this value as a 'pipeline parameter' that is accessible for subsequent steps? Also, is there a way to pass such dynamic parameters even between jobs?

Something like this

```
jobs:
    build:
        steps:
            - run:
                name: Generate UID
                command: |
                    UID=$(date +%s)
                    << pipeline.parameters.UID >> = UID # Store UID in the job context

            - run:
                name: Run Tests
                command: |
                    UID = << pipeline.parameters.UID >> # Retrieve UID from the job context
                    ./do_something.sh ${UID}
```

I can't seem to find the exact answer in the CircleCI documentation. Looked at

- https://circleci.com/docs/reusing-config#parameter-syntax
- https://circleci.com/docs/env-vars#setting-an-environment-variable-in-a-job

I might be close to the solution but I feel stuck and appreciate any help.

Comment: You could write the value to a file on the agent filesystem and then read it in a successive step. This assumes the same agent filesystem for both steps. Does that sound ok?

Comment: This may work if the same agent performs all steps in the job. Thanks to your idea I found Workspaces which seems to be the way of passing files even between jobs. See lines 17 and 38. I'll give it a try. Thanks for the tip.
https://circleci.com/docs/workspaces#workspace-configuration

Answer (score 4):

You can use a temp Env. variable to write into and read from it:

```yaml
steps:  
  -  run:  
    name: Post release to GitHub repo 
    command:  |  
     set -e 
     rel_id=$(./scripts/post-internal-release.sh) 
     echo "export REL_ID='$rel_id'" >> $BASH_ENV
```

To read it back:

```yaml
run:  
  name: Upload mapping files to github 
  command:  |  
  ./scripts/upload_mapping_to_github.sh ${REL_ID}
```

I've written a [comprehensive guide](https://blog.mhashim6.me/circleci-shell-guide/) on edge cases like these

Answer (score 1):

I needed to pass a value from a bash script up to the CircleCI script; not quite the same problem, but near enough that this answer may help someone else who finds this question. I think in this case, persisting the workspace and writing to a file is the best solution?

findValue.sh

```
...
if [ $DO_THE_THING == false ]; then
    echo "No action required"
    echo "no-action-required" > /tmp/do-the-thing-output.txt
  else
    echo "Action required" 
    echo "do-the-thing" > /tmp//do-the-thing-output.txt
fi
```

CircleCI workflow:

```
steps:
  - *attach_workspace
  - run:
      name: "Check if action required"
      command: |
        sh ./findValue.sh
        action_required="$(cat '/tmp/do-the-thing-output.txt')"
          if [ $action_required == "do-the-thing" ]; then
             echo 'Action required, continue to next step'
          else
             echo 'No Action required, halting'
             circleci-agent step halt
          fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use [CircleCI Workspaces](https://circleci.com/docs/workspaces#workspace-configuration) and persist the parameter that needs to be passed into a file.

```
jobs:
    build:
        steps:
            - run:
                name: Generate UID
                command: |
                    uid=$(date +%s)
                    mkdir -p workspace
                    echo ${uid} > workspace/uid

            - persist_to_workspace:
                root: workspace
                paths:
                    - uid

            - attach_workspace:
                at: /workspace

            - run:
                name: Use UID
                command: |
                    uid=$(cat workspace/uid)
```

The `attach_workspace` step may only be needed when passing data between jobs but it does no harm when passing data between steps.

Comment: The solution you applied is quite convoluted. Someone earlier suggested using CircleCI's `$BASH_ENV` (https://circleci.com/docs/env-vars#setting-an-environment-variable-in-a-shell-command); much simpler ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯